# Python TypeError when calling recursive function: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, recursion, return, typeerror

I am calling the function below to determine the index of matching items given an adaptive threshold for comparison, but I cannot get the return to function properly. It continuously returns nothing or produces the TypeError detailed below. When I follow the function through with a small example I can see it should return True and a list of False boolean values, but it will not actually do so. Please see the function below:

```
def inspect_combined_check(combined_check, threshold, multiple_match_marker):
    
   # Check to see if any row has a value over the required number of hits (Also returns index of hits)
   threshold_idx = combined_check >= threshold

   # Check sum to see the number of matches given the hit threshold
   num_matches = sum(threshold_idx)

   # ---Provide different paths for different numbers of matches---
   # Handle no match
   if num_matches < 1:
       # Means there are no matches, return marker indicating multiple matches and the zero indexes
       return threshold_idx, multiple_match_marker

   # Handle single match
   elif num_matches == 1:
       # Means there is a single match, return position of match
       return threshold_idx, multiple_match_marker

   # Hadle multiple matches
   else:
       # Look at next threshold level
       threshold += 1
       # Save marker of multiple matches
       multiple_match_marker = True
       # Run function again (resursively)
       threshold_idx, multiple_match_marker = inspect_combined_check(combined_check, threshold, multiple_match_marker)
```

When I throw in some print statements I can trace the values matching what I expect, but they don't actually return and present the error below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18124\1984272176.py in <module>
      2 combined_check = np.array([4,4,3,1,1,0])
      3 # Run function
----> 4 a,b = inspect_combined_check(combined_check, 2, False)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18124\1657509516.py in inspect_combined_check(combined_check, threshold, multiple_match_marker)
     32         multiple_match_marker = True
     33         # Run function again (resursively)
---> 34         threshold_idx, multiple_match_marker = inspect_combined_check(combined_check, threshold, multiple_match_marker)
     35 

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18124\1657509516.py in inspect_combined_check(combined_check, threshold, multiple_match_marker)
     32         multiple_match_marker = True
     33         # Run function again (resursively)
---> 34         threshold_idx, multiple_match_marker = inspect_combined_check(combined_check, threshold, multiple_match_marker)
     35 

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

The example I am using to test it is:

```
# Test recursive function
combined_check = np.array([4,4,3,1,1,0])
# Run function
a,b = inspect_combined_check(combined_check, 2, False)
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no `return` in the `else` branch. In python, no explicit `return` is the same as `return None`. Hence, `inspect_combined_check` returns `None` when the `else` branch is reached.

Comment: Since you always want to return `(threshold_idx, multiple_match_marker)`, you should write `return threshold_idx, multiple_match_marker` at the very end of the function, rather than inside the `if` and `elif` branches.

Comment: You can combine the first two cases with `num_matches <= 1`